# Why IntPtr.ToInt32 throws OverflowException in 64 bit mode and Explicit(IntPtr to Int32) doesn't

Tags: 64-bit, clr, intptr

The operator's [description on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a8d37fb.aspx) has a remark:

> An exception is only thrown if the value of value requires more bits
>   than the current platform supports.

while [`ToInt32`'s description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.toint32.aspx) doesn't so I suppose the title is not entirely correct(for brevity),

a more correct question would be: "Why `IntPtr.ToInt32` throws `OverflowException` in 64 bit mode for values that *fit in Int32* and Explicit(IntPtr to Int32) doesn't"

In decompiled `IntPtr` `ToInt32` and the operator look very similar:

```
public static explicit operator int(IntPtr value)
{
  return (int) value.m_value;
}

[ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
public unsafe int ToInt32()
{
  return (int) this.m_value;
}
```

I wonder what makes `ToInt32` throw the exception, is it the unsafe keyword?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your disassembler can't do a proper job here, mscorlib.dll is special.  It is not an AnyCPU assembly, Microsoft builds and ships different versions of it, based on the processor architecture.  I'd recommend you use the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx), you'll get the original source code.  Which looks like this:

```
    [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
    public unsafe int ToInt32() {
        #if WIN32
            return (int)m_value;
        #else
            long l = (long)m_value;
            return checked((int)l);
        #endif
    }
```

It is the *checked* keyword that provides the OverflowException.